# Override touch animation while showsTouchWhenHighlighted is TRUE

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

The default animation is to glow in the middle point.
How can I override the behaviour to highlight the whole button without using images - ie. getting the same effect of UITableViewCell is selected.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The UIView.backGroundColor is animatable so this may work

```
button.backGroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
button.backGroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Thanks @amleszk, I played with this solution a bit as well, it seems to be ok. I was just wondering there should be some method to override in a subclass, which should be a cleaner way to do it. Atm, I will probably go with the above solution. :)